# Know when notification reaches mobile

Tags: android, ios, node.js, firebase-cloud-messaging

My question is about
How can i know when the notification sent by backend (node js) is received at mobile ( android and ios) to make the chat i’m building with seen feature like whatsapp

Anyone have any ideas ?

Edit:
I’m trying to do chat that have seen and sent features
When client send msg to server via socket i can know when it’s delivered to the server
But how the server knows when the notification he sent received by the phone when the app is killed ?

Comment: client (android/ios) can dispatch events via WebSocket or REST to the server whenever the service detect the notification

Comment: It’s not advisable to do that .. ios system could block the app’s background services

Answer (score 0):

If there isn't a function in react, node or whatever tech stack you are using that actively responds to the camera on the phone registering the data that holds its users face when your notification goes off, then you need to know system programming for the phone. But, I think you may be chasing the wrong metrics.

If 3 apps go off, and somebody looks at the phone, how do you know if your notification got the attention of your user?

If 3 apps go off at different times of the day, but the user opens his or her phone 3 hours from the time of the first app and see's all notifications on the home screen, is that a good metric? Well, it's data but its not the metric you WANT.

A better metric would be : If my app goes off, and the users face looks at the phone within 5 seconds then that is data I can use.

Comment: How the comment is related to my question?